# (Django jwt token) get specific user with user id

Tags: python, django, authentication, jwt, backend

Current I am retrieving user data with the `UserViewSet` like this:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer 
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

What I did was to make a `GET` request the via the endpoint `` `http://localhost:8000/account/auth/user/${id}` `` together with a Bearer jwt Token on the header. However, I realized that I can get the all the user with the same jwt token because of the `Account.objects.all()`, which is not I wanted at all. I want to get the specific user corresponding to their id with their unique jwt token. Anyone has an idea how to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: then why not use request.user for that?

Comment: can you be more specific? I should I override the default request? much appreicated

Comment: I tried this: user = Account.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id) - but the request just return {
    "detail": "Not found."
}

Comment: Oh you are tying to get users from Account model?

Comment: yes, it is my custom user model

Comment: `class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer 
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Account.objects.all()

    def get(self):
    
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            user = Account.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
            self.check_object_permissions(self.request, user)
            return user` ------- I have tried this, still I can get all user with one single jwt token

Comment: do you need to get list of all user as well? or only need to perform loggedin user retrieve update delete operations?

Comment: No need to do that at this moment, I just want to get the specific user with respect to its access token.

Comment: In this situations I'm doing `queryset = User.objects.none()` and then override `def get_queryset(self): return User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)`. So every user can access only it's own record.